Hide input components streamlit
import os
from PIL import Image
import streamlit as st
from openai import OpenAI
from utils import (
    delete_files,
    delete_thread,
    EventHandler,
    moderation_endpoint,
    is_nsfw,
    render_custom_css,
    render_download_files,
    retrieve_messages_from_thread,
    retrieve_assistant_created_files,
)

# Inicializa una variable de estado para controlar la visibilidad del cuadro de texto
show_password_input = True  # Initially show password input

# Inicializa una variable de estado para controlar la visibilidad del desplegable de clientes
show_client_dropdown = False

st.set_page_config(page_title="BOOMIT AI",
                   page_icon="")

img_path = r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Boomit\desarrollos\BOOMITAI\company_logo.png"

img = Image.open(img_path)
st.image(
    img,
    width=200,
    channels="RGB"
)
st.subheader(" BOOMIT AI")
st.markdown("Analítica de marketing inteligente", help="[Source]()")
# Apply custom CSS
render_custom_css()

# Initialise session state variables
if "file_uploaded" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.file_uploaded = False

if "assistant_text" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.assistant_text = [""]

if "code_input" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.code_input = []

if "code_output" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.code_output = []

if "disabled" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.disabled = False

clientes_por_equipo = {
    "equipo_verde": ["BONOXS", "LAFISE PN", "LAFISE RD", "LAFISE HN", "ALIGE"],
    "equipo_amarillo": ["KASH", "DLOCALGO", "BANPAIS"],
    "equipo_azul": ["ZAPIA", "HANDY", "BOOMIT"]
}

# Define a placeholder option
placeholder_option = "Seleccione un equipo"

# Update the list of team options to include the placeholder
team_options = list(clientes_por_equipo.keys())
team_options.insert(0, placeholder_option)

# Selection of team
equipo_seleccionado = st.selectbox("Seleccione un equipo:", team_options, index=0, key="equipo_seleccionado")

# Check if the selected team is the placeholder
if equipo_seleccionado == placeholder_option:
    # Set the selected team to None to indicate no selection
    equipo_seleccionado = None

# Define team passwords in a dictionary
team_passwords = {
    "equipo_verde": "verde",
    "equipo_amarillo": "amarillo",
    "equipo_azul": "azul"
}

# Password input and validation
if equipo_seleccionado:
    if show_password_input:
        password_input = st.text_input("Ingrese la contraseña del equipo:", type="password")
        if st.button("Validar"):
            if password_input == team_passwords.get(equipo_seleccionado):
                st.success("Contraseña correcta!")
                show_password_input = False  # Hide password input after successful validation
                show_client_dropdown = True  # Show client dropdown
            else:
                st.error("Contraseña incorrecta. Intente nuevamente.")

# Display client dropdown only if password is correct
if show_client_dropdown:
    # Password validated, display client dropdown
    clientes = clientes_por_equipo.get(equipo_seleccionado, [])
    if clientes:
        cliente_seleccionado = st.selectbox("Selecciona un cliente:", clientes, key="cliente_seleccionado")
        # Your code to proceed with selected client (optional)
        # ...

# ... (rest of code)

I need to hide the password input box and the ok validation message after password validation is OK, and only show the client selection input box.

You can use the st.session_stateto keep the information that a user has correctly logged in. By default it is set to False, but as soon as the user guesses the correct password, they are set to st.session_state.loggedin = True.
Also, I set a st.rerun() just after changing the loggedin to True so that the app is refreshed with the new info and therefore does not show the password input anymore.
import streamlit as st

if "loggedin" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.loggedin = False

clientes_por_equipo = {
    "equipo_verde": ["BONOXS", "LAFISE PN", "LAFISE RD", "LAFISE HN", "ALIGE"],
    "equipo_amarillo": ["KASH", "DLOCALGO", "BANPAIS"],
    "equipo_azul": ["ZAPIA", "HANDY", "BOOMIT"],
}

# Define a placeholder option
placeholder_option = "Seleccione un equipo"

# Update the list of team options to include the placeholder
team_options = list(clientes_por_equipo.keys())
team_options.insert(0, placeholder_option)

# Selection of team
equipo_seleccionado = st.selectbox(
    "Seleccione un equipo:", team_options, index=0, key="equipo_seleccionado"
)

# Check if the selected team is the placeholder
if equipo_seleccionado == placeholder_option:
    # Set the selected team to None to indicate no selection
    equipo_seleccionado = None

# Define team passwords in a dictionary
team_passwords = {
    "equipo_verde": "verde",
    "equipo_amarillo": "amarillo",
    "equipo_azul": "azul",
}

loggedin = st.session_state.get("loggedin", False)

# Password input and validation
if equipo_seleccionado and not loggedin:
    password_input = st.text_input("Ingrese la contraseña del equipo:", type="password")
    if st.button("Validar"):
        if password_input == team_passwords.get(equipo_seleccionado):
            st.success("Contraseña correcta!")
            st.session_state.loggedin = True
            st.rerun()
        else:
            st.error("Contraseña incorrecta. Intente nuevamente.")
            st.session_state.loggedin = False

if loggedin:
    clientes = clientes_por_equipo.get(equipo_seleccionado, [])
    if clientes:
        cliente_seleccionado = st.selectbox(
            "Selecciona un cliente:", clientes, key="cliente_seleccionado"
        )

